# Can't type keyboard but all lock keys (caps lock, screen lock, num lock are all light up)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, keyboard, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

First of all, sorry for my bad english. 
I have an usb keyboard. Yesterday, I unplugged it from the PC (OS: Windows 7. And the PC was off when I unplugged the keyboard) to clean the dust from my keyboard. Nothing major, like flipping it upside down and shaking it and also wiping the dust off the cable. When I plug it again (the PC was still off), all the LED lights from 3 lock keys are all on but pressing the lock key doesn't turn it off. I didn't think about it and unplugged it so the light doesn't interfere with my sleep. Next morning when I plug it in to use it after turning the PC on, I can't type anymore (All 3 lights are on whenever I plug the keyboard in but can't be turn off). 
I try restarting the PC but it doesn't help. I try uninstalling the keyboard driver but upon reboot the driver doesn't automatically reinstall so now I'm also missing the Keyboards Submenu (I remember it was a Standard PS/2 Keyboard driver that I uninstalled but I could be mistaken) in Device Manager. I try plugging the keyboard into my laptop (try both usb port) and it doesn't help (the 3 lights are still on every time it plugged in) but when i plug my laptop mouse into the laptop usb port then the mouse is still working fine. 
Any help about the keyboard or the missing driver is appreciated. Thanks in advance everyone

P/S: Should I try manually install a keyboard driver for my PC. If so, how can I search for the appropriate driver? Should I search by the motherboard of the PC and the OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the keyboard driver is not being installed, then the keyboard
is not detected by Windows.

However, it's still drawing power, which explains the LED lights
still being on.

In my opinion, when you shook the keyboard, then some weak connection
gave way. In other words, the keyboard is broken.

There is no point in repairing it, as this will cost more than a
new one.
As keyboards are cheap, I suggest replacing it with a new keyboard.

I do not recommend connecting to the computer a broken keyboard
that is still drawing power. A short-circuit can have disastrous
results.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I will try to get a new keyboard soon after the Covid lockdown. It was an old and cheap keyboard so your explanation makes a ton of sense